# SQL Server : basic if condition in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have problem with basic `if` condition in function.. I have something like this

```
IF  LEFT(@text, 1) = '#'
        BEGIN
            /* trim first character if is '#' */
            RETURN RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-1)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            RETURN @text
        END
    END
```

Console output show me this

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

I wonder where the problem is. Can I simplify the if condition like this?

```
IF  LEFT(@text, 1) = '#'  RETURN RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-1)
ELSE RETURN @text
```

Thank you

edit: now I have that if in function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Trimming (@text VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TrimText AS VARCHAR(255) ;

    SET @TrimText=LTRIM(RTRIM(@text)
    IF  LEFT(@TrimText, 1) = '#'
        BEGIN
            RETURN RIGHT(@TrimText,LEN(@TrimText)-1)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            RETURN @TrimText
        END
END
```

and console says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code. http://i.stack.imgur.com/TwBAh.png

Comment: Thank you for image, one END was additional :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional `END` statement, your query should look like:

```
IF  LEFT(@text, 1) = '#'
BEGIN
     /* trim first character if is '#' */
      RETURN RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      RETURN @text
END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/270ca/4

**From your edit**

```
SET @TrimText=LTRIM(RTRIM(@text)
```

You are missing a `)`

```
SET @TrimText=LTRIM(RTRIM(@text))
```

Comment: Thank you it helped.. i rewrite it to this http://pastebin.com/mpJ9cd6E but now im getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Comment: @Muflix - pastebin is blocked on my network.  Can you include it in a SQLFiddle or modify your question to include the code?

Comment: Thank you, now it works i only have to add RETURN before last END because Console says last statement must be return.. but it is necessary if i have IF/ELSE there ? (okay i just deleted ELSE section now its perfect :-)

Answer (score 1):

The last `END` is not necessary since an `IF` does not require an `END`.
Also, since you only have one statement inside the `IF` and another one inside the `ELSE`, you don't need to write `BEGIN` and `END`.